# NEST: How to handle array fields which contains a single value (Newtonsoft Json Serialization error)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

During the evaluation of ElasticSearch in combination with NEST I faced a new problem.
The problem is regarding to fields which are array types plus the fact that array types are automatically supported in ES. I have a field ProductIds which can contain 1 or n values. The mapping is defined as following:

```
[…]
    "ProductIds" : {
        "type" : " integer",
        "store" : "yes"
    },
[…]
```

If the field contains a couple of Ids the query result in ES looks like this:

```
ProductIds: [
    1,
    2
]
```

The fact that array types are automatically, the field looks like this if it contains only a single value:

```
    ProductIds: 1
```

This circumstances leads to the following problem:
I do have a Nest-query which is mapped to an certain class. In this class the attribute ProductIds is defined as a `List<int>` (I also tried it with an integer array). This works perfectly fine as long as there is more than a single value. If the field contains only a single value in ES it’s saved as a primitive data type. This leads to an error in Newtonsoft.JSON:

> Connection error.    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)

So any suggestions how to solve this problem? TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not the first to run into this a solution has been provided here:
https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/issues/227#issuecomment-16550076

Support for this out of the box in NEST is planned too.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, haven't seen the issue on GitHub in the first place.